# Developer Story Privacy Features

Tags: discussion, feature-request, developer-story, privacy

Developer Story is a feature that has a great deal of potential when it comes to showing a prospective employer the skills one might have. Sadly, I've never used it simply because of privacy concerns — mainly what others are able to see and not having finer grain control.

Without getting into specifics on why someone would want more control, many would tend to agree on the importance of privacy, so I would like to suggest the following:

1. Allow users to see who visited their Developer Story (similar to LinkedIn).
2. Option to disassociate a Profile from it's Developer Story.
   <sub>(making the public unaware that the two are connected).</sub>
3. Privacy settings that allow the user to set the following:
   <sub>A. Unlisted Developer Story (which would allow only those with a special one-time generated  link to view it).

   B. Ability to only allow prospective employers which you've applied to ability to view.

   C. Whitelisting/Blacklisting capability</sub>

Generally speaking, greater privacy comes down to many things really (someone might work in a position that requires confidentiality and privacy, current employers might take note, or simply because someone likes to have more privacy while trying not to appear reclusive).

I welcome others' thoughts on the subject, or if some of these features already exist, please let me know. Thank you, Stack Overflow, for taking the time to consider these suggestions; all the best.

Comment: How is "Allow users to see who visited their Developer Story (similar to LinkedIn)" even in the same universe as "privacy features"?

Comment: @CodyGray: An example might be If someone was viewing a Developer Story and the user didn't want that particular person to view it then they could revoke access to them. Just knowing period is a way of ensuring that only specific people are viewing it.

Comment: @l'L'l But what about the privacy of the users who are viewing your Story?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: The focus shouldn’t really be on point one, and users viewing your story already have privacy.

Comment: @l'L'l Which you're suggesting removing. I support the rest, but that specific point is a little niggle.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Sure, I can see your point; perhaps the option could work mutually in some way, meaning that both users could appear anonymous unless some predefined conditions are met.

Comment: If you hide the developer story tab in your profile, does that satisfy your disassociation requirement?

Comment: @Jeremy: If it was hidden nobody else would be able to see it I don’t think; if it wasn’t hidden then of course it would be easily associated with a profile.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really agree with any of these.

> 1. Allow users to see who visited their Developer Story (similar to LinkedIn).

That just trades one privacy problem for another: users viewing the page lose *their* privacy.

> 2. Option to disassociate a Profile from it's Developer Story.
>      <sub>(making the public unaware that the two are connected).</sub>

You can already accomplish essentially the same thing, by creating a second account that you use solely for your CV/Developer's Story.

> 3. Privacy settings that allow the user to set the following:
>      <sub>A. Unlisted Developer Story (which would allow only those with a special one-time generated  link to view it).
>
>      B. Ability to only allow prospective employers which you've applied to ability to view.
>
>      C. Whitelisting/Blacklisting capability</sub>

All of these seem like problems best solved by keeping your Developer Story private and just sending a copy of it to people you want to see it. Now, you could say that they would be able to copy and forward it to whomever, but they could do that with a link as well. They would be copying the page's content rather than a link, but there's nothing you can do to stop that once their browser has the data.

The only problem not solved by this is blacklisting, but I see that as a separate issue. You probably don't really care whether they see your Developer Story or not; you simply don't want to hear from them. This should be available as an option independent of your Developer Story.